# Spurious Info in MySQL Logs

Tags: mysql, logging, configuration

I've recently enabled general query logging to my local MySQL server.

It was successful (although perhaps a little too successful) as the logs contain much 'spurious' information that I don't know where it's coming from.  It's certainly not coming from my query.

My query is:

```
select * from CT_DATASET where ID >= 0 and ID <= 1000
```

In the general_log this is what I find:

```
160204 14:05:13    36 Connect   root@localhost on cTLarge
           36 Query /* mysql-connector-java-5.1.38 ( Revision: fe541c166cec739c74cc727c5da96c1028b4834a ) */SELECT  @@session.auto_increment_increment AS auto_increment_increment, @@character_set_client AS character_set_client, @@character_set_connection AS character_set_connection, @@character_set_results AS character_set_results, @@character_set_server AS character_set_server, @@init_connect AS init_connect, @@interactive_timeout AS interactive_timeout, @@license AS license, @@lower_case_table_names AS lower_case_table_names, @@max_allowed_packet AS max_allowed_packet, @@net_buffer_length AS net_buffer_length, @@net_write_timeout AS net_write_timeout, @@query_cache_size AS query_cache_size, @@query_cache_type AS query_cache_type, @@sql_mode AS sql_mode, @@system_time_zone AS system_time_zone, @@time_zone AS time_zone, @@tx_isolation AS tx_isolation, @@wait_timeout AS wait_timeout
           36 Query SET character_set_results = NULL
           36 Query SET autocommit=1
           36 Query SET net_write_timeout=600
           36 Query select * from CT_DATASET where ID >= 0 and ID <= 5000000
160204 14:05:39    36 Query SET net_write_timeout=60
           36 Quit
```

It gives me the information I need (in this case the query execution time) but I've no idea where the initial SELECT is coming from and would ideally like to remove it (and all of the @@parameters_x AS parameters_x 'redundant' information) as it really clutters up the logs.

How may/can I remove this info from the logs (whilst still retaining the other information in the log)

Incidentally, the corresponding 'slow' logs are much more succinct:

```
# Time: 160204 14:05:39
# User@Host: root[root] @ localhost [127.0.0.1]  Id:    36
# Query_time: 26.232623  Lock_time: 0.000000 Rows_sent: 4929568  Rows_examined: 4929568
SET timestamp=1454591139;
select * from CT_DATASET where ID >= 0 and ID <= 5000000;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.  Checking the source code at https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/ shows:

```
StringBuilder queryBuf = new StringBuilder(versionComment).append("SELECT");
                queryBuf.append("  @@session.auto_increment_increment AS auto_increment_increment");
                queryBuf.append(", @@character_set_client AS character_set_client");
                queryBuf.append(", @@character_set_connection AS character_set_connection");
                queryBuf.append(", @@character_set_results AS character_set_results");
                queryBuf.append(", @@character_set_server AS character_set_server");
                queryBuf.append(", @@init_connect AS init_connect");
                queryBuf.append(", @@interactive_timeout AS interactive_timeout");
```

The library is executing the query and it is being logged correctly.

You can tell mysql not to log the lines. From 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_histignore :

> --histignore
>
> A colon-separated list of one or more patterns specifying statements
>   to ignore for logging purposes. These patterns are added to the
>   default pattern list ("*IDENTIFIED*:*PASSWORD*"). The value specified
>   for this option affects logging of statements written to the history
>   file, and to syslog if the --syslog option is given. For more
>   information, see Section 4.5.1.3, “mysql Logging”.

I've not tested but you might try:

```
histignore="*IDENTIFIED*:*PASSWORD*:*mysql-connector-java*"
```

in your my.cnf file.